# How to write recipients address in electronic cover letter for PhD program

Tags: application-cover-letter

I am going to send my cover letter for a PhD program, but I don't know who should I address exactly (I have written Dear Professors). Now the problem is for postal address what should I write. I don't know who exactly will receive the application.

Thank you

Comment: _"I don't know who exactly will receive the application."_ Well, neither do we. Why not email the admin office of the department you're applying to to find out the address and addressees?

Comment: Is there a website?  What does it say?

Comment: Yes there is a website. There is written  "SEDE " which, I think, in English means "head office" , and there is an address under it. There is as well director name in another part of the website. Is it better to write her address instead of Admission Board?

Comment: Well actually there isn't only one department. All different majors apply through the same application page. OK, thanks I will ask the "SEDE" director to know what should I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may vary by culture, but the common procedure for this case (letter that looks like a traditional letter, but is only sent electronically), the common procedure in Germany is to write something into the place where the recipient's address would normally go - but not necessarily an address: Something generic such as

> University of ...
>   Admission Board

should do.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is an Italian university and I think for Italy it could be the same.